# Grep from one line and print specfic text above that line

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I am currently facing a challenging script where I need to grep for the following 700e10 for example under the column partnum and find/grep for "rstcb" above that line. The problem is that it is not a fixed number of lines above the grep for "rstcb".

```
rstcb 700000036d048e8 tid 19150545
isfd  op_mode    op_flags   partnum   ucnt ocnt lk ra   partp          ocnt ucnt
0     400        297        700da0    2    2       1    700000023b8c028 715  715
1     2          3          700da0    2    2       0    700000023b8c028 715  715
2     1000400    403        700e10    1    0       0    70000002c768738 0    604
3     1000400    403        700e11    1    0       0    70000002c89a028 0    302
4     1000400    3          70051e    1    1       0    7000000242a1028 318  698
5     1000440    3          70051f    1    1       0    7000000242a15c8 318  396
```

Steps to get this

Step 1:
`Select hex(partnum) from systables where tabname = "stocks"`

Output for example:
`0x00700e10`

Step 2: (informix)
Run `onstat -g opn | grep -i 700e10`

Step 3:
You will get the the above text from image for example

I would like to include a grep that can search for the text rstcb above the initial result from step 2. Once I have that I would like to `awk '{print $2}'`
the number 700000036d048e8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the requirement right, a brief `awk` should do it:

```
$ cat > test
rstcb 999999999999
rstcb 700000000123
foo bar doo partnum
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 7001e0

$ awk -vkey=7001e0  '/^rstcb/ {val=$2; next} $4 == key {print val; exit}' test   
700000000123
```

This saves the second field of any line starting with `rstcb`, and prints the saved value (the last one) if a line is met where the fourth field matches `7001e0` or whatever `key` was set to on the command line.

The `next` in the first code block skips the second test, and the `exit` is there to stop after the first match. If you remove that, you get multiple hits, but they might be from the same `rstcb` line.